# PHP Code not working (Insert to DB)

Tags: php

I have a db connection and want to test inserting a variable value into a db field. It's not inserting anything but cannot see why...can anyone spot the problem please?

Updated - here's all the php code:

```
    //DB Conn

<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
    mysql_select_db('mydb',$link);
?>

    ... then
    //Save.php

    <?php

    include('dbconn.php');

    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

        $mytestvalue = 'hello';

        $query="insert into mytable (id, name) values ('null','".$mytestvalue ."')";

    ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because you're never actually executing that query…?

Comment: Where's the code where you perform the query?

Comment: 'null' is not `NULL`, it's literally the word null...

Comment: @DanGrossman means it should look like this: `$query="insert into mytable (id, name) values (NULL,'".$mytestvalue ."')";`. However if ID is a auto_increment primary key then there is no need to even pass in `NULL` you can just leave ID out of the insert query for the same effect.

Comment: You should do corrections in code you actually run, but It is better to leave the code in your question intact. People have pointed you miss a call to `mysql_query($query, $link);` and you put it in (and in the wrong place), now the answer looks irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the actual call to [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in your code that actually executes the SQL you have created.

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Add the line above to the end of the code sample in your question.

Please see [this example on the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#example-1517) for a fully worked example of an interaction with MySQL from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql_query function should be after you define the  actual query string.

So, you first define the $query  and THEN execute the mysql_query function call.

Cheers!